# Flash Builder 4.6 Mac installer fails

Tags: installation, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I tried to install Flash Builder 4.6 tonight and the installer fails. Per the on line directions I first uninstalled FB 4.5. Now I cannot get either the 4.6 installer or the 4.5 installer to work. Both fail with a nondescript error "The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Conatact the software manufacturer for assistance."

Mac OS 10.7.3

Any suggestions?

Update: I had a dual boot system with an SSD sharing a home folder on the internal drive of my MacBookPro. Tonight I moved the home folder to the SSD so that it is now a normal boot drive with it's own home folder. Now the Installer runs without any errors and says that the files were installed successfully, but nothing is installed. At least I cannot find any trace of Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe TS solved my problem. I had downloaded the wrong installers. The installers I had were Akamai installers. Not sure how I got the wrong installers. TS had me go to the same place I had gone previously, only this time the proper installers were downloaded.

Be aware that if you are upgrading from 4.5. that the 4.5 installers are no longer available on line. Unless you have the installer on disk or archived someplace, you will not be able to go back.